# Remove part of url link being created by variable

Tags: php, variables, hyperlink

I have a link that is created by a variable as below:

```
<div class="pdf-download">
   <a href="/images/documents/187/pdf-test.pdf|Download">Download</a>
</div>
```

This is being created by the following:

```
<div class="pdf-download">
   <a href="/images/documents/<?= $this->item->id; ?>/<?= $pdfdownload ?>">Download</a>
</div>
```

I need to remove the "Download" from the url that is created by *$pdfdownload*.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace '`|Download`' with an empty string with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php).

```
 <a href="/images/documents/<?= $this->item->id; ?>/<?= str_replace('|Download', '', $pdfdownload) ?>">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `|Download` is always at the end,
you can replace `$pdfdownload` with `preg_replace('/pdfdownload\|$/','',$pdfdownload)`